# Captum vs GNNExplainer for explainability in Graph Neural Networks

Tags: deep-learning, explainable-ai, graph-neural-network, pytorch-geometric

I'm new to Graph Neural Networks and interested in exploring frameworks that allow the identification of nodes/edges that underlie prediction.

I came across :
(1) [a model architecture (GNNExplainer)](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/nn/models/gnn_explainer.html) as well as
(2) [a tool (Captum)](https://captum.ai/docs/introduction.html),

which both seems to achieve this goal, but I'm not able to appreciate the differences between the two. Does Captum work with all model architectures, including GNNExplainer? Can anyone point me to some pros/cons of each, or distinguish them apart by applications/capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

The latest Pytorch Geometric library supports direct usage of GNNExplainer and model conversion to captum, which can be further used for feature attribution.

GnnExplainer is a framework that computes the minimal subgraph that produces the same output as close to the original graph.

Captum is a library that is built for interpretability on Pytorch. Captum primarily supports Integrated gradients which is an input-attribution based explanation method that can be applied to any differentiable model, not only GNNs.